# Codeigniter image manipulator Unable to save the image

Tags: php, codeigniter

Well i have the following problem:
I'm using CodeIgniter 2.1.3 and want to upload an image and create two scaled images. one that is resized to the size of around 50x50 and one that is resized to around 200x200.

Uploading is doing fine.

But when i want to resize the following error occures:
**Unable to save the image. Please make sure the image and file directory are writable.**

I've set my permission on the server to 777, but it still doesn't compute

Here is the code of the classes:

```
public function uploadimage()
    {

         $head = array('title' => 'Upload Image');
        $error = array('error' => '');
                 $this->load->view('head',$head);
                 $this->load->view('imageUpload', $error);
                 $this->load->view('footer');
    }

    public function changeimage()
    {
          $config = array();
          $config['upload_path'] = 'img/Upload';
          $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp';
          $config['max_size']   = '100';
          $config['max_width']  = '200';
          $config['max_height']  = '200';
          $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
          $config['file_name'] = md5($this->session->userdata('username')).".png";

          $head = array('title' => 'Upload Image');
          $this->upload->initialize($config);

          if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
          {
                 $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                 $this->load->view('head',$head);
                 $this->load->view('imageUpload', $error);
                 $this->load->view('footer');
          }
          else
          {
             $uploaddata = $this->upload->data();

              //Create Thumb
              $config2 = array();
              $config2['image_library'] = 'gd';
              $config2['source_image']  = $uploaddata['full_path'];
              $config2['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
              $config2['width']  = 50;
              $config2['height'] = 50;
              $config2['new_image'] = '/~3612546/DateSite/img/ProfileThumbs/'.$uploaddata['file_name'];
              $this->image_lib->initialize($config2);
              if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize())
              {
                echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
              }

              //Create resized original image so images < 200x200 get resized to get as close to 200x200
              $config3 = array();
              $config3['image_library'] = 'gd';
              $config3['source_image']  =$uploaddata['full_path'];
              $config3['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
              $config3['width']  = 200;
              $config3['height'] = 200;
              $config3['new_image'] = '/~3612546/DateSite/img/ProfileImages/'.$uploaddata['file_name'];
              $this->image_lib->initialize($config3);
              if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize())
              {
                  echo $uploaddata['full_path'];
                  echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
              }

          }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i really don't think tilde is good for upload urls:

```
/~3612546/DateSite/img/ProfileImages/
```

then, all your urls are upper/lowercase, put them all to lowercase like this:

```
/~3612546/dateSite/img/profileimages/
```

in the end post what error do you receive now that you chmod 777 your upload folder, do you added 777 only to dir or dir+all his content? (it's important dir+all his content to 777)

Comment: the Uppercases are not the problem. But how do i 777 the dir + content

Comment: @user2271176 are you on win or macosx? usually right clicking on the folder with mouse you got how to setup permissions, usually there is "add permissions to all files inside" , are you on macosx?

Comment: im on windows but i use putty to get on the server, which is in linux.

Comment: @user2271176 sorry the server you connect to is windows too? or linux?

Comment: here if it's windows http://superuser.com/questions/106181/equivalent-of-chmod-to-change-file-permissions-in-windows

Comment: oke i found my problem:
i set the permission to 777 while i was working with it. So i created a couple of new map which i first set the permission to 777 and then started writing to them, which worked :)